# SQL 2005 Transactional Replication: Behavior during snapshot processing?

Tags: sql, replication

So, I've got SQL (2005) Transactional Replication generally working well with a single publisher and single (read-only) subscriber.  Data changes and updates flow perfectly, with about 5 second latency, which is just fine.

My one nagging problem, that I've spent a couple days trying to solve (and Googling everywhere for answers) is that *new* sprocs/tables/etc. do not get propagated to the read-only subscriber, even though I've added them as "articles" to the "publication".  The publication has "transmit schema changes" set to ON, and stored procedures are set to transfer their definitions.  But, for some reason, they don't.

My "snapshot agent" process is set to NOT SCHEDULED.  (In other words, it only happens once, when I initiate it manually.)  Should I be putting this on a schedule to enable the transfer of new or modified tables and sprocs?

I thought the mere act of adding the object as an article to the publication would do it, but it's still not sending it unless I do a snapshot.  The WAN connecting these is totally fast and reliable, so that's not the issue, and table-data-updates transfer relatively fast and flawlessly.

While I could put my snapshot agent on a schedule, does this have any real-time production impacts for users of the main publication database or the read-only copy?  (My site currently gets 4+ million unique-users a month, so I'd like to have minimal disruption...)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactional replication only distributes (and then subsequently publishes) the DML (Data Manipulation Language) statements from the transaction log of the source (publication) database.

New tables and stored procedures are not replicated to the subscriber. Schema changes in this particular context, although I have to admit it is a little unclear in some of the Books Online documentation, refer to the existing schema, i.e. if you were to a add column to an existing database this change would be propagated to the subscribers.

For clarification here is a Microsoft article that details the schema changes that you can make.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870(SQL.90).aspx][1]

I hope this helps. Replication is a big subject area so please let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Oh yes, you are correct, if you add new articles to your publication you will need to create an updated snapshot.

Cheers,